# Yum No Package available Java JDK

Tags: java, linux, centos, yum, centos7

I had an old link a rmp.bin file to a version of JDK I don't think exists in any repro's anymore so I downloaded it onto my box and tried to install it but I keep getting the error below. How do I determine what the issue is? I assumed that since I had the actual .bin file that yum would have everything it needed?

```
sudo yum install jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                                                                                                               | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                               |  14 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                               | 4.4 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                             | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                            | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
(1/3): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                  |  33 kB  00:00:00     
(2/3): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                 | 4.2 MB  00:00:00     
(3/3): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                      | 3.4 MB  00:00:01     
(1/2): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                      | 105 kB  00:00:00     
(2/2): epel/x86_64/pkgtags                                                                                                                         | 1.3 MB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * epel: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * updates: mirror.fdcservers.net
No package jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the binary package first; it will self-extract to an rpm file, which in turn can be installed with yum, after you accept the license.

```
chmod 744 jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
./jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
(read and accept the license)
yum localinstall <extracted rpms>
```